# Extract/echo text from div from one iframe, onto another part of the page

Tags: html, css, iframe, echo

So if it's possible I'd like to echo (or otherwise copy) some text from inside one iframe on a custom page i'm making into another section/div on the page this iframe is on.

Example:

```
<div 1>
  <iframe> 
    <div inside frame>
       Text i would like to echo/copy
    </div>
  </iframe>
</div>
<div 2>
  (another iframe could go here if needed but i was firstly trying to do it without another one.)
  Text from the iframe above 
</div>
```

I may not have that 100% right but i'd like to do that and in the second div i'll have a class that makes the text scroll.

The use for this is a twitch stream project i'm working on. This is taking text that shows 'now playing' from a page and making it transparent via having the background color 'chroma key green' and displaying it on the stream.

The other option is if I could have some sort of script to send the text from this div into a text file as it updates and then i could add the text file to the stream instead.

note: I don't mind using php or java/jquery. I was trying to keep the file simple to use and edit most of all. I just wanted to note i'm not as experienced in java and php. I want to do this the simplest way possible.
Thanks!

(I don't want to include all my code, but it's fairly straight forward, all help is appreciated.)

Comment: Are the parent page and the iframe hosted on the same domain? If not, are you able to modify the source of the iframe page to add JavaScript to it?

Comment: No, the parent page is hosted locally as a standard html file. The iframe itself is embedded into the parent page (there are actaully 4 other iframes on the page pulling other things to the page as well. but I only need to access a certain div inside one of the iframes. I can add java to the parent page, not to the embedded iframe (unless you can add java to the embedded iframe of course, as i noted not that good with java.)

thanks!

Comment: cont. If it helps, the iframe links to nightbot.tv/autodj . The div on the page i want to copy/echo has an id="currentTitle" so i'm not sure i can grab that somehow or not.

Comment: Unfortunately, it sounds like what you are asking is not possible given your scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If the parent page and the page inside the iframe are hosted on the same domain**, you can access the contents of the iframe directly with something like this on the parent page:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('id-of-iframe');
var element = iframe.documentWindow.getElementById('id-of-element-inside-iframe');
```

For security reasons, this will fail if the pages are not hosted on the same domain.

**If the pages are hosted on different domains, but you have access to both** (read: you can change the HTML output from the server on both pages), you have another option called cross-document messaging.

This is a bit more complex, and involves scripts on the parent and child page to communicate with each other and send data back and forth.

On the parent page, you would have something like:

```
window.attachEventListener('onmessage', function (...) {
  // Listen for messages from the child page
}, false);
```

And then in the child page, you would package up the data and send it to the parent with a call like this:

```
parent.postMessage(...);
```

Obviously, there are details I've left out here (...), but this is the general idea.

**If you don't have access to both the parent and child page**, there is no way to achieve what you're asking. Allowing any page to access any other page inside an iframe would be a major security problem. (Imagine if I placed a full-page iframe on my site, loaded Gmail in it, then setup a script to watch the value of the password field.)

Comment: Understandable. Although i'm curious if it would however be possible to pull information from a random page, or for example take this question on this page and pull the question title (from the 'question header' section. and only pull the text from this page onto the other in the form of text only. 

Of course you can't edit the page here, but Just for research purposes.

Comment: Thank you for all your help btw! nice to know what you can and cannot do sometimes!

Comment: No, browsers won't let you do anything to access a page on a different domain unless it is specifically shared with you via the cross-document messaging process mentioned above. The way most sites pull data from external sources is with web services and AJAX calls.